# Error with using Ngu Carousel with Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use this carousel (https://github.com/sheikalthaf/ngu-carousel) with Angular 4 but I keep getting this error.

[image]

After having all imports in the App module and in the component, I have simplified the the code in the template to this and still error does not go away. Any ideas?

```
<ngu-carousel [inputs]="carouselOne" (carouselLoad)="myfunc($event)">
    <ngu-item NguCarouselItem>
      <div>--1--</div>
    </ngu-item>
    <ngu-item NguCarouselItem>
      <div>--2--</div>
    </ngu-item>
</ngu-carousel>
```

Below is the code in the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NguCarousel, NguCarouselStore } from '@ngu/carousel';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-squad',
  templateUrl: './new-squad.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-squad.component.css']
})

export class NewSquadComponent implements OnInit {

  public carouselOne: NguCarousel;
  public positions: Array<string> = [];
  public players: Array<string> = [];
  private form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("here.........");
    this.carouselOne = {
      grid: {xs: 1, sm: 1, md: 1, lg: 1, all: 0},
      slide: 1,
      speed: 400,
      interval: 4000,
      point: {
        visible: true
      },
      load: 2,
      touch: true,
      loop: true,
      custom: 'banner'
    }
  }

 onmoveFn(data: NguCarouselStore) {
    console.log(data);
  }

  public myfunc(event: Event) {
     // carouselLoad will trigger this funnction when your load value reaches
     // it is helps to load the data by parts to increase the performance of the app
     // must use feature to all carousel
  }

  public saveSquad(f) {
    console.log(f.value);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/squads', f.value)
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these two buttons,

```html
<button NguCarouselPrev class='leftRs'>&lt;</button>
<button NguCarouselNext class='rightRs'>&gt;</button>
```

Looking through the source code for [ngu-carousel.component.ts](https://github.com/sheikalthaf/ngu-carousel/blob/master/src/ngu-carousel/ngu-carousel.component.ts) there are several references to `nativeElement` in ngOnInit(). I'd say the following are most likely the cause the problem

- this.rightBtn = this.next.nativeElement;
- this.leftBtn = this.prev.nativeElement;

where `this.next` and `this.prev` are set by

```js
@ContentChild(NguCarouselNextDirective, { read: ElementRef })
private next: ElementRef;
@ContentChild(NguCarouselPrevDirective, { read: ElementRef })
private prev: ElementRef;
```

Comment: That was it!! Thank you very much!!